# material-1.3.0\res\values\values.xml:3523:23: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconSize' with config ''

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The issue occur when I upgrade to androidX.
I have removed all the custom font and style which are used in the project.
Also remove and change the .xml files used for different shapes.

Answer (score 0):

look for the 'iconSize' attribute in your project in res/values/values.xml
it says there are duplicate values for this  'iconSize' attribute,
delete one of them